# Cauchy problem and operator theory problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Would you mind giving only hint to me in order to start to solve???

> Let 
>   $T : C([0, 1]) \to C([0, 1]) $ 
>   be the linear operator defined by 
>   $T(f) := y,$ 
>   where y is the solution of the Cauchy problem
>   $$y'(x)=y(x)+f(x),\;\;\; y(0)=0$$
>   (a) Prove that $T$ is compact.
>
> (b) Prove that $T$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: Could you please tell us, if you remember, where this exercise was taken from? I would like to have a source of similar problems. Thanks

Comment: https://www.math.sissa.it/entrance-examinations/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Using the product rule with integrating factors, we find that $$\frac{d}{dx}(y(x)e^{-x}) = y'(x)e^{-x}-y(x)e^{-x}=f(x)e^{-x}$$ So integrating both sides from $0$ to $u$ and then multiplying by $e^{u}$ we find $$y(u) = \int_0^uf(x)e^{u-x}dx=Tf(u)$$

To prove that $T$ is compact, I suggest using the fact that $|f(x)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ in order to show that the collection $\{Tf:\|f\|_{\infty}<1\}$ is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded in $C[0,1]$.

To show that $T$ has no eigenvalues, then suppose that $$\lambda f(u) = \int_0^u f(x)e^{u-x}dx$$ Now differentiate both sides of this equation with respect to $u$ and you will see that $f$ satisfies a differential equation which is easily solved, with the initial data $f(0)=0$. Can the resulting function be an eigenvector?

Comment: thanks in advance. I see that 
$\ln(f(u))=\frac{1}{\lambda}-1\;\Rightarrow f(u)=\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda}u-1).$
Now, I don't see any problem with it.
Actually, $\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda}u-1)\in C([0,1])$

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari You have to remember that the initial data forces $f(0)=0$. Now you are almost correct about solving the differential equation, but you forgot the constant which uses the initial data. We actually get that $f(u)=f(0)\exp(\lambda^{-1}u-1) = 0$, since $f(0)=0$. Now this is a contradiction, since $0$ can never be an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the differential equation

$y'(x) = y(x) + f(x), \; y(0) = 0, \tag 1$

defined on the unit interval $[0, 1]$, is given by the formula

$y(x) = e^x \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f(s)ds, \tag 2$

as may readily be seen by direct differentiation; from (2):

$y'(x) = (e^x)'\displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f(s)ds + e^x (\int_0^x e^{-s}f(s)ds)'$
$= e^x \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f(s)ds + e^x ( e^{-x}f(x)) = y(x) + f(x); \tag 3$

we corroborate that $y(x)$ satisfies the requisite initial condition:

$y(0) = e^0 \displaystyle \int_0^0 e^{-s}f(s)ds = 0. \tag 4$

We will show the map $T:C([0, 1]) \to C([0, 1])$ given by

$T(f) =  e^x \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f(s)ds \tag 5$

is compact *via* the [Arzela-Ascoli Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).  Let $f_n(x) \in C([0, 1])$ be a sequence such that

$\Vert f_n(x) \Vert \le 1 \tag 6$

for every $n$; that is, $f_n(x)$ lies in the unit ball of $C([0, 1])$; then setting

$y_n(x) = T(f_n(x)), \tag 7$

we have

$\Vert y_n(x) \Vert = \Vert e^x \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \Vert \le \Vert e^x \Vert \Vert \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \Vert$
$\le e \displaystyle \int_0^x \Vert e^{-s} f_n(s) \Vert ds \le  e \displaystyle \int_0^x \Vert e^{-s} \Vert \Vert f_n(s) \Vert ds \le e \displaystyle \int_0^1  1ds = e, \tag 8$

which shows the sequence $y_n(x) = T(f_n(x))$ is *uniformly bounded*.  Now suppose $x_1, x_2 \in [0, 1]$ with $\vert x_1 - x_2 \vert < \delta$, and say, without loss of generality, $x_2 \ge x_1$; then we have the following somewhat gory presentation of an estimate for $\vert y_n(x_2) - y_n(x_1) \vert$:

$\vert y_n(x_2) - y_n(x_1) \vert = \vert e^{x_2} \displaystyle \int_0^{x_2} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \ -  e^{x_1} \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert$
$= \vert e^{x_2} \displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds + (e^{x_2} -  e^{x_1}) \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert$
$\le \vert e^{x_2} \vert \vert \displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert + \vert (e^{x_2} -  e^{x_1}) \vert \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert$
$\le e \vert \displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert + \vert e^{x_1}(e^{x_2 - x_1} - 1) \vert \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert$
$\le e \displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \vert  e^{-s}f_n(s) \vert ds + \vert e^{x_1} \vert \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert$
$\le e \displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \vert  e^{-s} \vert \Vert f_n(s) \Vert  ds + e \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} e^{-s}f_n(s)ds \vert$
$\le e \displaystyle \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \Vert f_n(s) \Vert  ds + e \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} \vert e^{-s}f_n(s) \vert ds$
$\le e(x_2 - x_1) \Vert f_n(x) \Vert + e \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} \vert e^{-s} \vert \Vert f_n(s) \Vert ds$
$\le e \delta + e \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} \vert e^{-s} \vert \Vert f_n(s) \Vert ds$
$\le  e \delta + e \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \displaystyle \int_0^{x_1} \Vert f_n(s) \Vert ds \le e \delta + e \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert \Vert f_n(x) \Vert x_1 \le e(\delta + \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert); \tag 9$

now, given $\epsilon$, we may choose $\delta$ sufficiently small that

$\delta + \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert < \dfrac{\epsilon}{e}; \tag{10}$

then we have

$\vert y_n(x_2) - y_n(x_1) \vert \le e(\delta + \vert e^\delta - 1 \vert) < e\dfrac{\epsilon}{e} = \epsilon, \tag{11}$

independently of $n$, $x_1$ or $x_2$; thus the sequence $y_n(x)$ is in fact *equicontinuous*; thus the hypotheses of [Arzela-Ascoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) are met, and we conclude that $y_n(x)$ contains a *uniformly convergent subsequence*; we conclude that $T$ is indeed [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator).

We show that $T$ has no eigenvalue.  If $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ *were* an eigenvalue of $T$, then by (5) we would have

$e^x \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{-s}f(s)ds = T(f(x)) = \lambda f(x) \tag {12}$

for some $0 \ne f(x) \in C([0, 1])$; setting

$g(x) = e^{-x}f(x), \tag {13}$

we see that

$\displaystyle \int_0^x g(s) ds = \lambda g(x), \tag {14}$

and since $f(x) \in C([0, 1])$, the integral $\int_0^x e^{-s}f(s) ds = \int_0^x g(s)ds$ is differentiable in $x$, so (14) yields

$g(x) = \lambda g'(x); \tag{15}$

if now $\lambda = 0$, we have

$f(x) = e^x g(x) = \lambda e^x  g'(x) = 0, \tag{16}$

forbidden for an eigenvector of $T$; if, on the other hand, $\lambda \ne 0$, by (15) $g(x)$ satisfies the differential equation

$g'(x) = \lambda^{-1} g(x) \tag{17}$

with $g(0) = 0$ from (14).  We thus must have, by uniqueness of solutions, $g(x) = 0$ on $[0, 1]$, and

$f(x) = e^x g(x) = 0 \tag{18}$

for all $x \in [0, 1]$, again forbidden by the definition of eigenvectors.  This contradiction implies there is no legitimate  $f(x) \in C([0, 1])$ satisfying (12); $T$ is a compact operator without eigenvalues.

Comment: thanks in advance. How do you say (18) is equal to zero?

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari:  note that $g(x)$ satisfies (17) with $g(0) = 0$.  Then $g(x) = 0$ on $[0, 1]$ by uniqueness of the solutions to ODEs.  Thus $f(x) = e^x g(x) = 0$ etc.  Seen?

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari:  I added a few words to hopefully make this more clear!

Comment: $\ln(g(x))=\frac{1}{\lambda}x-C\;\Rightarrow g(x)=\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda}x-C).$

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari:  have remarks but can't reply right now must go to work later thiis evening perhaps?  Thanks.

Comment: OK. TNX. I will wait.

Comment: @HamedBaghiGhaffan: The ***unique*** solution to $g'(x) = \lambda^{-1}g(x)$ on $[0, 1]$ is   $g(0) \exp(\lambda^{-1} x)$; this holds for ***all*** $g(0)$ and is found by intelligent "guessing", the derivation based on $\ln g(x)$ only works if $g(x) \ne 0$, but is a useful heuristic for finding the correct solution $g(0) \exp(\lambda^{-1} x)$ which works for ***all*** $g(0)$.  Cheers!