# to prove an integral operator with a kernel is compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

emphsisingly, I just need a hint not a whole solution please.

> **Problem**:
>   Consider the operator
>   $T:C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$defined by 
>   $$ (Tf)(t):=\int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)f(s)ds $$ 
>   where 
>   $k:[0,1]^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$
>   satisfies the following
>
> - for all 
>     $t\in [0,1],$
>     the function
>     $k_{t}(s)=k(t,s)$
>     is integrable in $s$:
>     $$ \int_{0}^{1}k(s,t)ds<\infty, $$
> - the function 
>     $ t\mapsto k_{t}\in L^{1}([0,1]) $
>     is continuous.
>
> Show that $T$ is compact.

Comment: You might try constructing a proof which parallels that given inhttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398606/cauchy-www-and-operator-theory-problem.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe, It would be OK the same way proof and try it to this question. But I was in doubt. Or it maybe better to write the same method to this question and ask about its correctness here.

Comment: It's more or less what Aweygan proposed in his answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem to show that the image under $T$ of the closed unit ball of $C([0,1])$ is relatively compact.  To this end, observe that for $f\in C([0,1])$ with $\|f\|\leq1$, we have 
$$|Tf(t)|\leq\int_0^1|k(s,t)|ds$$
for $t\in[0,1]$ (to help establish a uniform bound), and 
$$|Tf(t_1)-Tf(t_2)|\leq\int_0^1|k(s,t_1)-k(s,t_2)|ds$$
for $t_1,t_2\in[0,1]$ (to help establish equicontinuity).